# Does AutoMapper have modules?

Tags: automapper

My AutoMapper configuration classes are spread over the different projects they belong to, i.e. Business.SalesDtoAutomaps vs. Presentation.SalesViewModelAutomaps and set up like so:

```
public sealed SalesDtoAutomaps {
 public static void Configure()
 {
    Mapper.CreateMap<...>()
    Mapper.CreateMap<...>()
    Mapper.CreateMap<...>()
 }
}
```

All of the *Automaps get called in Global.asax on app start. Is there actually a proper way to do this, similar to [Autofac modules](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules)?

If there is a module-esque approach, is there also a way to easily inject dependencies into it, as that is quickly becoming a need for my configurators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For centralized configuration of your mappings, look into Automapper Profiles.  Simply create a class that inherits from Automapper.Profile and ovveride the Configure method.  Put all your CreateMap calls there (well, not ALL, but the ones that pertain to that profile).